# executeUpdate() throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement, indexoutofboundsexception

I have been trying to execute the following query :

```
SQL_ADDPROJECT = "INSERT INTO project (name, description, duration, departement, chef) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

using:

```
public boolean addProject(String name, String description, String duration, String budget, int chef, int departement) {
    try {
        addProject_statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_ADDPROJECT);
        addProject_statement.setString(1, name);
        addProject_statement.setString(2, description);
        addProject_statement.setString(3, duration);
        addProject_statement.setString(4, budget);
        addProject_statement.setInt(5, chef);
        addProject_statement.setInt(6, departement);

        int res = addProject_statement.executeUpdate();
        if ( res != 0 ) {
            addProject_statement.close();
            return true;
        } 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;               
}
```

I call addProject this way :

```
save_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String name = nameField.getText();
        String description = descField.getText();
        String duration = durationField.getText();
        String budget = budgetField.getText();
        int chef = User.userId;
        int departement = User.departementId;
        if(name != null && duration != null) {
            if ( dao.addProject(name, description, duration, budget, chef, departement) ) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Project " + name + " created successfully!");
                MainMenu menu = new MainMenu();
                menu.setVisible(true);
                frame.dispose();
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill in the form correctly!");
            }
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

but everytime I try to execute i get a message dialogue that says `5`

followed by another message dialogue that says `Please fill in the form correctly`

Knowing that i did fill it correctly!

Trace :

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at org.sqlite.core.CorePreparedStatement.batch(CorePreparedStatement.java:121)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.setInt(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:324)
    at database.SqlConnection.addProject(SqlConnection.java:75)
    at project.addProject$4.actionPerformed(addProject.java:196)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: In the catch can you please print the stacktrace and add it...

Comment: @utkarsh31 now that i saw the trace i know where it's coming from, thanks!

Comment: Happy to help :)..

Comment: It doesn't *only* say `5`. It says `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` too, and the value says that it's at index 5. Your problem is that SQL only has 5 `?` markers, but you're adding 6 values. `setInt(6, departement)` doesn't work. Also, the order of your values don't match the SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`addProject_statement.setString(4, budget);`  has no matching argument in the `SQL` statement so number of values (and their type) do not match.

For

```
SQL_ADDPROJECT = "INSERT INTO project (name, description, duration, budget, departement, chef) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Use

```
 addProject_statement.setString(1, name);
 addProject_statement.setString(2, description);
 addProject_statement.setString(3, duration);
 addProject_statement.setString(4, budget);
 addProject_statement.setInt(5, departement);
 addProject_statement.setInt(6, chef);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are adding 6 values in the addProject_statement but there are only 5 params in the Insertquery, thats what is causing the issue...

Comment: That's right. The order of the set statements is also wrong.

Comment: agreed, that also needs to be fixed

Answer (score 1):

You statement isn't ordered. there's no budget and departement is before chef.

```
public boolean addProject(String name, String description, String duration, String budget, int chef, int departement) {
    try {
        addProject_statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_ADDPROJECT);
        addProject_statement.setString(1, name);
        addProject_statement.setString(2, description);
        addProject_statement.setString(3, duration);
        addProject_statement.setString(4, departement);
        addProject_statement.setInt(5, chef);
```

Comment: I believe you need to add `addProject_statement.setString(4, budget);`  and change `SQL` accordingly